# How to match Euro € sign in javascript regexp with octal, hexadecimal or unicode metacharacter?

Tags: javascript, regex, unicode, hex, octal

I need to create samples of hexadecimal and octal metacharacters use in regexp. I found on the Internet [link](http://www.ascii-code.com) that octal code for € is `200` and hexadecimal is `80` but when I try to match € with regex `\200` and `\x80` it does not match € sign. Only unicode metacharacter `\u20AC` works fine. Do I have wrong codes or it is not possible to match euro sign with oct and hex metacharacters? I haven't had this sort of problem with other characters before.

```js
var a = "200€"

console.log(a.search(/\200/g));     //-1
console.log(a.search(/\x80/g));     //-1
console.log(a.search(/\u20AC/g));   //3
```

Comment: In link you provided octal value is 200 not 128. number 8 is not a valid value in octal system

Comment: corrected, thank you

Comment: Could be a bug, it works for `£` symbol. [link](https://regex101.com/r/upB82L/1)

Answer (score 1):

As I have just found out, taking as an example **pound** `£`, the unicode for pound `£` is `00A3` or shortened `A3` which can be used in javascript regexp as `\u00A3` *{four hexadecimal digits metacharacter}* or as `\xA3` *{two hexadecimal digits metacharacter}*. `A3` hex number parsed to octal number equals `243` what means that `\243` as *{three octal digit}* metacharacter also matches `£`. The problem with `€` is that it's unicode is `20AC` what means that it can be used as `\u20AC` *{four hexadecimal digits metacharacter}*, but it cannot be shortened to *{two hex digits}* while it does not begin with `00`. `20AC` parsed to octal equals `20254` what causes that it cannot be used as *{three octal digit}* as well.

To sum up, only the characters which can be expressed in two-digit hexadecimal code can be matched as `\xdd` regexp metacharacter, and only the characters which can be expressed in three-digit octal code can be matched as `\ddd`. So € `U+20AC`, ❤ `U+2764`, ☯ `U+262F`, ❄ `U+2744` and thousands of other characters can be matched only with `\udddd` metacharacter in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In Unicode, the code point for the euro sign is U+20AC, not U+0080. There are some 8-bit encodings which use 0x80 for the Euro sign, notably Windows-1252, but this has nothing to do with Unicode. There's simply no way to match the euro sign with an 8-bit hex or octal escape sequence in JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

Try this pure javascript hack (lalz):

```
var txt = 'This will cost 3€';
console.log(encodeURI(txt).indexOf('%E2%82%AC'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it may be some kind of a bug.

```js
console.log("Euro symbol: \x80");
console.log("Pound symbol: \xA3");
```